# PHP5, SOAP and 64 bit Debian machine

Tags: php, soap, pear

I've recently updated the versions of PHP5 and Apache2 on 2 debian machines. I have SOAP services on them both (they're both behind a load balancer), and on one they work, the other they don't.

The one that doesn't work is a 64 bit machine. I'm using PEAR SOAP and wondered if anyone had seen any issues like it or knew of any work arounds?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Had it working in 64bit (actually, come to think of it: have, not had..). Any errors in your logs? A sample input / output problem?

Comment: Turns out it wasn't a 64bit issue. It was to do with libxml2 and the version it upgraded it to after the php5/apache2 upgrade.

Had to downgrade libxml2 to a previous version, but that cascaded into all sorts of other problems. I've ended up having to roll everything back!

Answer (score 0):

Please use the PHP SoapClient class, it's more recent and stable.